# Visual Studio dataset weird behaviour

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dataset

For some reason, whenever I make any changes in the designer, it creates a new file:
[image]

`InventoryDataset1.Designer.cs` instead of making changes to the original one, later resulting in errors like

> Error 2   The type 'Inventory.InventoryDataSet' already contains a
>   definition for
>   'ItemsRowChangeEventHandler'  C:\Users\Robus\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\Inventory\Inventory\InventoryDataSet1.Designer.cs   461 30  Inventory

I've tried deleting the previous designer file and replacing it, but I keep getting errors. Whenever I try to make changes (doubleclick od the .xsd and changing something in the designer) it only saves the changes to the `InventoryDataSet1.Designer.cs` file. How can I fix this? What did I do wrong?

Comment: This might help you perhaps. It seems to be the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534796/dataset-designer-issue-visual-studio-2008?rq=1

Comment: @Thorias This fixed the creation of new files, but now once I save the designer, all TableAdapters disappear :|

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea how to solve that problem.